# matrix game, condition when user selects 2 same colored balls it should destroy the 2 same color patterns

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

i am trying for a matrix game, the condition is:

- when user selects 2 same color ball,that will destroy the 2 same color patterns.

I have done horizontal & vertical selection correctly. But when i am trying for a cross selection(diagonal) it not working, i think, i have done a mistake in a diagonal selection condition.

This is my coding, the cross selection didn't matching the same color pattern. This is my 
diagonal selectin coding, is the below condition is correct?

```
    onCheckPattern: function(pPattern) {
    if (pPattern != null) {
        this.mPromptTimerTally = 0;
        this.mPromptMarkSpr.setPosition(-1000.0, -1000.0);

        if (this.mFirstCheckPattern === null) {
            this.mFirstCheckPattern = pPattern;
            this.mCheckMarkSpr.setPosition(this.mPatternsPos[this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex][this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nColIndex]);
        } else {
            this.mSecondCheckPattern = pPattern;
            if (this.mSecondCheckPattern === this.mFirstCheckPattern) {
                //                    this.mSecondCheckPattern = null;
                //                    return;
            }

            var isAdjacent = false;

            //HORIZONTAL& VERTICAL
            if (this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex == this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex) {
                if (this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nColIndex > 0 &&
                    this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nColIndex - 1 == this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nColIndex)
                    isAdjacent = true;

                else if (this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nColIndex + 1 < this.m_nMatrixCol &&
                    this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nColIndex + 1 == this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nColIndex)
                    isAdjacent = true;
            } else if (this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nColIndex == this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nColIndex) {
                if (this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex > 0 &&
                    this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex - 1 == this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex)
                    isAdjacent = true;
                else if (this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex + 1 < this.m_nMatrixRow &&
                    this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex + 1 == this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex)
                    isAdjacent = true;

            }
            //       


            //DIAGONAL SELECTION
            else if (this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex + 1, this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nColIndex - 1 && this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex, this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nColIndex)

            {
                isAdjacent = true;
            } else if (this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex - 1 == this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex && this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nColIndex - 1 == this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nColIndex) {
                isAdjacent = true;
            }




            if (isAdjacent) {
                this.mCheckMarkSpr.setPosition(-1000.0, -1000.0);

                this.swapTwoPattern(this.mFirstCheckPattern, this.mSecondCheckPattern, false);
                this.mFirstCheckPattern = null;
                this.mSecondCheckPattern = null;
            } else {
                this.mCheckMarkSpr.setPosition(this.mPatternsPos[this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex][this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nColIndex]);

                this.mFirstCheckPattern = this.mSecondCheckPattern;
                this.mSecondCheckPattern = null;
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Please make proper use of punctuation and refrain from using multiple punctuation characters (ie .... or !!) and finish sentences with a dot, and let's not forget about using paragraphs / line breaks. I cleaned it up to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
            else if (this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex + 1, this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nColIndex - 1 && this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex, this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nColIndex)
```

looks suspicious to me.

Abbreviating somewhat, you're writing something like

```
            else if (a + 1, b - 1 && c, d)
```

Because of the way the [JavaScript comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) works, this gets interpreted as `else if (d)`, and so `isAdjacent` will be set to `true` if `d` is not zero.

Try

```
            else if (this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex + 1 == this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nRowIndex && this.mFirstCheckPattern.m_nColIndex - 1 == this.mSecondCheckPattern.m_nColIndex)
```

instead.